# Calculating multi-label inter-annotator agreement in Python

Tags: python, annotations, training-data, multilabel-classification

Can anyone recommend a particular metric/python library for assessing the agreement between 3 annotators when the data can be assigned a combination of labels (as seen below)?

|  | Msg_1 | Msg_2 | Msg_3 | Msg_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Annotator_1 | a,b,c | b | c | a,b,c |
| Annotator_2 | a,c | b | c | a |
| Annotator_3 | b,c | a,b | c | a,b |

I have tried python Krippendorff's Alpha implementations, however they don't seem to work with multilabels.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inter annotator agreement when users annotates more than one category for any subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174915/inter-annotator-agreement-when-users-annotates-more-than-one-category-for-any-su)